# What is the best practice of Global Dialog in my Application

Tags: android, dialog, android-context

I have my Custom dialog builder in my app that will trigger from many events like: Asynctasks, web service messages, UI input error or from services that don't have activity context. I always used to create a Activity called `currentActivity` in my Application class. then on resume of every activities their sit on `currentActivity`.

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MyApplication.currentActivity = MainActivity.this;
```

then in case of create dialogs I used that context. but I had one problem. for example I opened RegisterActivity and then `currentActivity` changed to it. then when app goto background or some case that some other activity opened, my app will crash on creating dialog with that Context. so handling witch Activity is `currentActivity` is a headache. I googled and find that some guys embed the CustomDialog in an non-layout activty and then open that activity. but it seems to not good solution.

**UPDATED**

for example I have a SMSManager class that handle my all sending sms. I wanna open dialog to user chose some custom options before sending sms.

so what is the best practice of Global Dialog in my whole application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all - it is a very bad practice to save references to activities (or `Context` in general). Android always provides you a reference to a `Context` object you can use for creating your dialog. In an `Activity` it is the object itself (`this`), in a `Fragment` you can access the `Context` by `getActivity()` or `getContext()`, in a `View` - `getContext()`.

If you need to display a dialog from your custom class and don't have the reference to the `Context` make sure, that you provide the `Context` reference to your class by using the methods described above.

Don't try displaying any dialogs from a `Service` - make sure your app is in foreground and visible, before showing any dialogs. You can use an event bus (or [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)) for sending the state (error, message or whatever) to your currently visible `Activity` or `Fragment`. The "current visible Activity or fragment" in this case is just the `Activity` or `Fragment` which is listening for such kind of events. Start listening in `onStart()` and stop listening in `onStop()` methods of your `Activity` or `Fragment`. If you don't want to rely on any running Activities for displaying a dialog and don't want to wait for the next time the user starts your app, I would suggest using [notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) instead of dialogs.

Given a `Context` you can create your custom dialog whereever you want by using a helper dialog builder class like this:

```
public class DialogBuilder {
    private String title;
    private String message;
    private String primaryButtonTitle;
    private String secondaryButtonTitle;
    private Dialog.OnClickListener primaryButtonListener;
    private Dialog.OnClickListener secondaryButtonListener;
    private Activity context;
    private boolean showIcon;
    private boolean cancellable;

    public DialogBuilder(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DialogBuilder setTitle(@StringRes int title) {
        this.title = context.getString(title);
        return this;
    }

    public DialogBuilder setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        return this;
    }

    public DialogBuilder setMessage(@StringRes int message) {
        this.message = context.getString(message);
        return this;
    }

    public DialogBuilder setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }

    public DialogBuilder setShowIcon() {
        showIcon = true;
        return this;
    }

    public DialogBuilder setPrimaryButton(@StringRes int title, Dialog.OnClickListener listener) {
        primaryButtonTitle = context.getString(title);
        primaryButtonListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public DialogBuilder setSecondaryButton(@StringRes int title, Dialog.OnClickListener listener) {
        secondaryButtonTitle = context.getString(title);
        secondaryButtonListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public DialogBuilder setCancellable(boolean cancellable) {
        this.cancellable = cancellable;
        return this;
    }

    public AlertDialog create() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_dialog, null);        
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        // get your custom views here and configure them based on given settings (field values of this class)

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

example usage (in a `Fragment`):

```
new DialogBuilder(getActivity())
    .setTitle(R.string.title)
    .setMessage(R.string.message)
    .setPrimaryButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do something
            dialog.dismiss();           
        }
    })
    .setSecondaryButton(R.string.settings_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do something
            dialog.dismiss();           
        }
    }).create().show();
```

Comment: I know that it's bad to keep currentActivity and I looking for better solution. my custom Dialog Builder is very similar to yours but the point it context. as I said in question I wanna Open dialog from many Classes that some of them don't have any activity context. for example I wanna show dialog from my SMS manager class or web service class that works with Application Context. so I can not Open dialog with their Context.

Comment: so you say that don't show any UI dialog from services, just broadcast some event and catch with activity. this sound good and matches with the MVC architecture. but what if my service wanna communicate with user and give some input?

Comment: for this case I suggested to use notifications. But in your special case (choosing options for an SMS before sending it) I would suggest to start an Activity from your Service. You can show your Activity as a dialog by applying a custom theme.

Comment: pardon me? how should i get input  (for example with sim card for sending sms ) in notification?

Comment: in fragments he can also use onAttach method which provides you with the context.

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom dialog class like this :

```
public class DialogBoardOut extends Dialog {

private TextView txtBoardOut;
private RelativeLayout rel_close_boardout;

public DialogBoardOut(Context mContext) {
    super(mContext);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_boardout);
```

}
}

call like :

```
 DialogBoardOut dialogQrCode = new DialogBoardOut(HomeBaseActivity.this);
            dialogQrCode.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            //  dialogQrCode.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialogQrCode.show();
            dialogQrCode.getWindow().setLayout(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: my problem is not with custom Dialog builder. it's about Context

Comment: If you want to use dialog in fragment then use getActivity().getApplicationContext() and in activity send getApplicationContext()

Please elaborate at which condition you don't have context.. so i will guide you